# Adequate Power Supply for 300 Daisy-Chained LEDs

Tags: power-supply, led, led-strip, electricity

I have 300 LEDs (ws2812b) wired in a series. They were sold as 150 LED/5 meters and rated to power at 9W/m, so 45W/5m strip. I would need 90 Watts to power my entire 300 LED strip. I have a 3-rail power supply that has an output of 5v 40A (200W), would this be adequate to power the LEDs?

Naively, I thought I could power them straight from the PS but got major color change around the halfway mark (expectedly where the second strip is connected). I soldered +V and -V of the second rail to the halfway point and it helped my situation but not entirely and I am worried I am going about it wrong. If anyone could shed some light (haha) on my situation I would greatly appreciate it !!!